# camel: Check if file is "eligible" for processing. If a file is not eligible for procssing move to next

Tags: apache-camel

The file process strategy checks databases for specific preprocess conditions/steps were executed before processing a file XYZ.

The files XYZ comes from different sub directories of a root directory that camel scans.

If one of the file is not eligible camel should move to the next one. Not sure what flag should I use if any so it won't bother checking the current file again and again instead of moving to the next one.

My File process Strategy:

```
 public class MigrFileProcessStrategy<T> extends GenericFileProcessStrategySupport<T> {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MigrFileProcessStrategy.class);

@Autowired
DefaultMigrationProcessor defaultMigrationProcessor;

@Override
public boolean begin(GenericFileOperations<T> operations, GenericFileEndpoint<T> endpoint, Exchange exchange, GenericFile<T> file) throws Exception {
//check if HIST table has entry for this filename, if yes all preprocessing done, file is ready.
boolean readyForProcessing = false;
String fileAbsPath = file.getAbsoluteFilePath();
File inMigrFile = new File(fileAbsPath);
readyForProcessing = defaultMigrationProcessor.isFileReadyForProcessing(inMigrFile);
if (!readyForProcessing) {
    String msg = String.format("\n####Process?:%b  File:%s", readyForProcessing, fileAbsPath);
    log.info(msg);
}
return readyForProcessing;
}
```

}

My Config:

```
<bean id="migrFilesToCopy" class="org.apache.camel.component.file.MigrFileFilter">
<!-- Filter for migr files that need to be copied-->
    <property name="caseSensitive" value="true" />
    <property name="excludes" value="**/**/*.migratedLnk, **/_inProgress/**, **/_done/**, **/_failed/**" />
</bean>


    <endpoint id="endpoint_migrFilesToCopy"
        uri="file://#{migrationProcessor.migrRootDir.toFile()}?processStrategy=#migrFileProcessStrategy&amp;directoryMustExist=true&amp;idempotent=true&amp;recursive=true&amp;delete=true&amp;initialDelay=1000&amp;delay=5000&amp;readLock=changed&amp;readLockTimeout=100000&amp;readLockCheckInterval=1000&amp;moveFailed=_failed&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=10&amp;filter=#migrFilesToCopy" />






    <route id="chMigrate" autoStartup="true">
        <from uri="ref:endpoint_migrFilesToCopy" />
        <pipeline>
            <log message="Procesing file: ${header.CamelFileName}" />
            <!--threads executorServiceRef="migrThreadPool" -->
            <bean ref="migrationProcessor" method="createMetadata" /><!-- MetaDataVo -->
            <bean ref="migrationProcessor" method="createCopyObj" /><!-- CacheCopyObj -->
            <bean ref="migrationProcessor" method="migrate" />
            <!--/threads -->
        </pipeline>
    </route>
```

**Resolved by extending ant filter:**

**public class MigrFileFilter extends AntPathMatcherGenericFileFilter implements GenericFileFilter {**
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MigrFileFilter.class);
    @Autowired
    DefaultMigrationProcessor defaultMigrationProcessor;
    public MigrFileFilter() {
    super();
    }

```
@Override
public boolean accept(GenericFile<T> file) {
String fileAbsPath = file.getAbsoluteFilePath();
File inMigrFile = new File(fileAbsPath);
boolean readyForProcessing = false;

if (Files.isDirectory(inMigrFile.toPath())) {
    readyForProcessing = true; //To recursivly process directories.
} else {
    boolean validFilePatten = super.accept(file);
    boolean preprocessDataExist = false;
    if (validFilePatten) {
    preprocessDataExist = defaultMigrationProcessor.isFileReadyForProcessing(inMigrFile);
    }
    readyForProcessing = (validFilePatten && preprocessDataExist);
}
return readyForProcessing;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the filter to filter out unwanted files

You can implement a custom implementation, and just return true|false if you want to include the file or not.

See the section *Filter using org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter* at

- http://camel.apache.org/file2

Comment: Thanks. Will check that. In my case the files are unwanted only until "preprocess steps are not done", once preprocess is done (say in 10min or 30min), the file becomes wanted and therefore be processed.

Comment: Thanks Claus, I extended the AntMatcher for custom filter. Resolved.